# Multiple indentation issues in the SEDE editor

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

Prior to the redeploy the other day, pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> on a line in the SEDE editor would create an indent of two spaces, and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> would un-indent by two spaces. Hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of an indented line would bring you to a new line with the same level of indentation

Now, pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> indents by a `\t`, and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> does nothing. Hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of an indented line brings you to a new line with the same level of indentation, but the tabs are replaced by four spaces (and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> still doesn't work).

I don't really mind the change from two spaces to `\t` for indentation, but the other two changes (loss of un-indentation and munging of indentation on new lines) are not great, particularly because the combination of them makes it inconvenient to un-indent on a new line (you have to backspace through multiple spaces).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, since it sort of works the same for the first line I guess I didn't notice when I upgraded CodeMirror back in November.

Restoring the behaviour you were expecting was thankfully easy due to CodeMirror's key map bindings though, so [fixed now](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/58) pending a pull and redeploy.